# change-data-capture from many tables via a single stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, change-data-capture

I need to retrieve change-data-capture rows for several tables, and I'm required (by company IT policy) to access the database via stored procedures.  I would rather create a single stored procedure with the table name as a parameter, rather than one stored procedure for each table I'm monitoring.  Where I get hung up is that CDC defines a separate table-valued function name for each table monitored, and I'm not sure how best to generalize around that.

Is it possible to modify the following example code so that it invokes `cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_dbo_ + @Table` instead of `cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_dbo_TABLE` ?

Is there another approach I should use?

```
create proc [dbo].GetChangesForTable
 @Table varchar(50),
 @BeginTime datetime,
 @EndTime datetime
as
begin

    DECLARE @begin_lsn binary(10), @end_lsn binary(10); 
    DECLARE @func nvarchar(128)

    if @EndTime is null select @EndTime=GETDATE()

    SELECT @begin_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('smallest greater than', @BeginTime); 
    SELECT @end_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('largest less than or equal', @EndTime); 

     -- HOW TO GET THE CORRECT FUNCTION CALLED HERE?        
    SELECT * FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_dbo_TABLE(@begin_lsn, @end_lsn, 'all')

end
GO
```

Comment: you'll need to use dynamic sql to add the table name to your sql before executing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's possible with `sp_executesql` like that :

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
    SET @sql = N'SELECT * FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_dbo_'+cast(@TABLE as varchar)+'(@begin_lsn, @end_lsn, 'all')'


EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@Table varchar(50), @BeginTime datetime, @EndTime datetime',@Table,@BeginTime,@EndTime
```